# Solspace Freeform: How to dynamically set admin notification email

Tags: solspace

Using Solspace's Freeform, how can I dynamically set the admin notification email address? Ideally i'd like to set this via Low Variables so that my client can change all of their contact information in one window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting your dynamic variable in the `admin_notify=""` parameter for `{exp:freeform:form}`. (Don't forget to use `notify_admin="yes"` as well if you haven't already enabled admin notifications in the Freeform module CP)

Here's an example using the {exp:channel:entries} tag pair and a custom channel field containing an email address called {my_email_address_field}. I'm assuming a similar strategy can be used with Low Variables.

```
{exp:channel:entries /* your other parameters here */}
  {exp:freeform:form
    notify_admin="yes"
    admin_notify="my_email_address_field"
    // Your other parameters, such as form_id="" or form_name=""
    }
    // Your form
  {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Make sure my_email_address_field is parsed correctly in the `admin_notify=""` parameter. You can confirm that by **turning on Template Debugging** in EE and looking for the {exp:freeform:form} tag containing admin_notify="".